# Does "tailoredly" exist as an adverb?

Tags: adverbs

Does the word "tailoredly" exist? I mean it as a synonym of "specifically."

For example,

> "the man responded tailoredly to the criticisms"

instead of

> "the man tailored his responses to the criticisms"

It seems plainly obvious to me that it should exist as a word, but I can't find a single dictionary entry on it, and it's never been used by the NY Times, Washington Post, or LA Times.

Comment: "The man gave responses tailored to the criticisms" is a possible re-wording.

Answer (score 2):

I can see the reasoning behind your question, but trust me, any native speaker who reads or hears that will conclude your English is very poor. No disrespect intended. :) Sadly, just about every 'rule' in the language has exceptions that sound "wrong", despite the fact there is no logical explanation why that is so.

Comment: If you're implying that it sounds like a non-native-speaker error, then I disagree; to me it reads more like a native speaker having fun with the language. (Though that really depends on the context, of course.)

Comment: @ruakh Quite so. If you speak with a knowing sense of amused irony, which both you and your interlocutor understand, you can coin words with abandon. But it has to be "ksai" - *knowing sense of amused irony*.

Comment: @ruakh is correct, I'm a native English speaker. Just for an indicator, I got a perfect score on the English portion of the ACT. I ain't got no Ph.D. in Linguistics, but I contest that my command of the language is "very poor."

Comment: Doubtless, and still using a term like that would make it appear you had a poor command… which doesn't mean you actually have, does it?

Answer (score 0):

I am truly sorry.  There is no proper forum that has or would in the future use "tailoredly" as a proper adverb.  If it were to be used by you in a sentence, unfortunately you would appear to have made a true grammatical error.  Although there is such a broad variety of adverbial words in our language, it is in fact improper to use as any form of adverb.  Just so that you understand when I say "any form" of adverb that I am referring to each whether it be superlative/comparative, what position it may be placed in or within your sentence, as well as an adjunct adverbial.  There    is no history within the most reputable news factions or prints having used "tailoedly".  Another idea might be to use a synonym for the word you intended on using.  I have found that sometimes a synonym for my intended word in a sentence actually looks, sounds,!and appears better fitting.  hope my answer was of help to you.  For future references you may want to check a thesaurus and get some ideas to use different forms of a word.

Comment: Can you amend your answer to explain why you think 'tailoredly' hasn't become a real word? It is truly not a real word, but it is nominally a well-formed adverb from an adjective/past participle, like 'assuredly' or 'understandably'.